# Binding and Using ngModel with Multi-nested JSON Object

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to bind and use ngModel with a JSON object that is double nested. This is what I'm trying to use: (Calendar from PrimeNG)

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields;">
    <div *ngFor="let player of field.players; let i = index;">
        PlayerID: {{player.playerid}}
        <div *ngFor="let goal of player.goals; let j = index;">
            {{goal.timestamp}} <p-calendar [showTime]="true" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" timeFormat="hh:mm" required [(ngModel)]="field.players[i].goals[j].timestamp"></p-calendar></span><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, only the first date value in the array is binded correctly, the others do not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use index for the `fields` as well.

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields; let fi = index;">
    <div *ngFor="let player of field.players; let i = index;">
        PlayerID: {{player.playerid}}
        <div *ngFor="let goal of player.goals; let j = index;">
            {{goal.timestamp}} <p-calendar [showTime]="true" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" timeFormat="hh:mm" required [(ngModel)]="fields[fi].players[i].goals[j].timestamp"></p-calendar><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still appears to produce the same issue.

Comment: I just tried it on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbjdyw and it worked.
I noticed that you added `</span>`  without opening `<span>`.
Is it a typo?

Comment: It may be that this markup is inside a `form` tag, and that each input field must have a different `name`.

Comment: I appreciate the help. It was a missing index and I had a goofy typo.